# Web scraping wrong output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a set of code to webscrape from basketball-reference.com. I am using the libraries request and bs4 within my code.

Here is my current code and output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Url of the webpage with Jimmy Butlers stats
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/butleji01.html" 

# Sends a GET request to the webpage
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content

# Creates a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

# Finds the HTML table that contains the stats
table = soup.find("table", {"id": "per_game"})

#Extratcs the headers of the tables I am wanting
headers = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
column_names = [header.text for header in headers]

#Finds the rows to correspond with Jimmy Butler
rows = table.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
jimmy_butler_row = None
for row in rows:
    if row.find("td").text == "Jimmy Butler":   
        jimmy_butler_row = row
        break

if jimmy_butler_row is not None:
    # Extract the statistics for Jimmy Butler
    pts = jimmy_butler_row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'pts_per_g'}).text     
    ast = jimmy_butler_row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'ast_per_g'}).text
    fg_percentage = jimmy_butler_row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'fg_pct'}).text
    ft_percentage = jimmy_butler_row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'ft_pct'}).text

# Stores the extracted statistics in a data structure
    jimmy_butler_stats = {
        "Points (PTS)": pts,
        "Assists (AST)": ast,
        "Field Goal Percentage (FG%)": fg_percentage,
        "Free Throw Percentage (FT%)": ft_percentage
    }

    # Print the extracted statistics
    print("Jimmy Butler's Statistics:")
    print("")
    print("2022-23 Season")
    for stat_name, stat_value in jimmy_butler_stats.items():
        print(stat_name + ":", stat_value)
else:
    print("Jimmy Butler's statistics not found.")
```

Current output:

```
Jimmy Butler's statistics not found.
```

My desired output is meant to look like this:

```
Jimmy Butler's Statistics:

2022-23 Season 
Points (PTS): 22.9 
Assists (AST): 5.3 
Field Goal Percentage (FG%): .539 
Free Throw Percentage (FT%): .850
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the HTML to see if it relates to Jimmy Butler. The URL you're using already guarantees that.

Thus your code can be much simplified:

```
import requests
import bs4

URL = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/butleji01.html'
CONTROL = {
    'Points (PTS):': 'pts_per_g',
    'Assists (AST):': 'ast_per_g',
    'Field Goal Percentage (FG%):': 'fg_pct',
    'Free Throw Percentage (FT%):': 'ft_pct'
}

with requests.get(URL) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    if (tr := soup.find('tr', id='per_game.2023')):
        for k, v in CONTROL.items():
            if (td := tr.find('td', attrs={'data-stat': v})):
                print(k, td.getText())
```

**Output:**

```
Points (PTS): 22.9
Assists (AST): 5.3
Field Goal Percentage (FG%): .539
Free Throw Percentage (FT%): .850
```

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't think to do it in that way. I appreciate that a lot, that is very helpful for me.

Comment: @NickR It's good practice to accept the solutions that met your needs. Accept DarkKnights solution, and go back to your previous asks and accept those too,

Answer (score 0):

You could also just let pandas parse the tables, then filter to a specific season and specific stats.

```
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/butleji01.html'
df = pd.read_html(URL)[1]
sesaon_2023 = df[df['Season'] == '2022-23']

cols = ['PTS', 'AST', 'FG%', 'FT%']
print(sesaon_2023[cols])
```

**Output:**

```
print(sesaon_2023[cols])
     PTS  AST    FG%   FT%
13  22.9  5.3  0.539  0.85
```